# Click binding not working

Tags: jquery, templates, knockout.js

I'm having trouble with the `click` binding. I'm trying to run some sample code from the Knockout website, which isn't working. The number of clicks isn't updating. I'm not getting any javascript errors in Firefox.  Can someone help?

This is the code I have:

```html
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/knockout-1.2.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var clickCounterViewModel = function () {
            this.numberOfClicks = ko.observable(0);

            this.registerClick = function () {
                this.numberOfClicks(this.numberOfClicks() + 1);
            }

            this.hasClickedTooManyTimes = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
                return this.numberOfClicks() >= 3;
            }, this);
        };

        ko.applyBindings(new clickCounterViewModel());
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div>You've clicked <span data-bind="text: numberOfClicks">&nbsp;</span> times</div>

<button data-bind="click: registerClick, enable: !hasClickedTooManyTimes()">Click me</button>

<div data-bind="visible: hasClickedTooManyTimes">
    That's too many clicks! Please stop before you wear out your fingers.
    <button data-bind="click: function() { numberOfClicks(0) }">Reset clicks</button>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to move your script tag to the bottom of the document or put it in a an onload/ready function.  You need at least `ko.applyBindings` to execute after the rest of the DOM has been loaded.

Comment: Wow... that stumped me for a while.  Thanks!!! It's knockout sample code... I wish they had specified!  @RP Niemeyer